# Passing variable into [icon] for Font Awesome not working

Tags: html, angular, font-awesome, angular-fontawesome

I am using Font Awesome with Angular.

I want to loop through some data via `*ngFor` to create icons in a navigation bar. However, the `[icon]` is not accepting the values from the variable.

Component HTML

```
<div class="navbar-container container" [ngClass] = "expanded ? 'navbar-collapsed': ''">
  <div class="navbar-logo-container">
    <button class="logo" (click)="toggleCollapsed()">
      A
    </button>
    <div class="logo-text" *ngIf="expanded">My Site</div>
  </div>
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="navbar-nav-item" *ngFor="let data of navData">
      <a class="navbar-nav-link" [routerLink]="[data.routeLink]">

        //works
        <fa-icon [icon]="['fas','star']"></fa-icon> 

        //Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'IconProp'.
        <fa-icon [icon]="data.iconfull"></fa-icon> 

        // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'IconProp'.
        <fa-icon [icon]="[data.iconfirst,data.iconsecond]"></fa-icon> 

        <span class="navbar-link-text" *ngIf="expanded">{{data.label}}</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Data

```js
export const navbarData = [
    {
        routeLink: 'dashboard',
        iconfirst: 'fas',
        iconsecond: 'star',
        iconfull: "['fas','star']",
        label: 'Dashboard'
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot reproduce the third scenario.

From [`IconProp`](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/65f4bdb5025759ba25cd3432568de288b6a67527/js-packages/%40fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/index.d.ts#L20),

```js
export type IconProp = IconName | [IconPrefix, IconName] | IconLookup;
```

Hence, for the second scenario,

Specify the `navbarData` type as:

```js
import {
  IconProp,
  IconPrefix,
  IconName,
} from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';

navbarData: {
  routeLink: string;
  iconfirst: IconPrefix;
  iconsecond: IconName;
  iconfull: IconProp;
  label: string;
}[] = [
  {
    routeLink: 'dashboard',
    iconfirst: 'fas',
    iconsecond: 'star',
    iconfull: ['fas', 'star'],
    label: 'Dashboard',
  },
];
```

[Sample Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ewuvqk?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I do see this working on StackBlitz but it is not working on mine. Different error but mostly the same.
Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'IconProp'.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '[IconPrefix, IconName]'.
    Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer.

Comment: Maybe you can also try to specify the type of `navbarData` as this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ewuvqk?file=src/app/app.component.ts).